# Consulta mysql com 3 critérios diferentes dentro da mesma tabela no BD

Tags: php, mysqli, inner-join

Preciso criar uma consulta *MySQL*/*PHP* com 3 critérios diferentes, mas que estão dentro da mesma tabela do BD.

> ```
> Tabela Negociações (Nome: tbl_neg)
> ID    STS     VALOR
>  1     1    R$23.000,00
>  2     2    R$60.000,00
>  3     1    R$10.000,00
>  4     1    R$50.000,00
>  5     6    R$20.000,00
>  6     2    R$88.000,00
>  7     6    R$15.000,00
> ```

Preciso fazer uma consulta nesta tabela, porém na coluna status (nome: sts) sempre vai existir três critérios, cito 1, 2 e 6, que eu preciso separá-los e depois soma-los.

Não sei se deu pra entender a minha “pergunta”. Estou pensando em algo como se fosse um join na mesma tabela, pois andei dando uma pesquisada no Pai (Google) e sei que existe. Seria possível usar algo tipo:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tb_neg a 
INNER JOIN tb_neg b ON a.stsneg = '1' AS analise 
INNER JOIN tb_neg c ON a.stsneg = '2' AS aprovado 
INNER JOIN tb_neg d ON a.stsneg = '6' AS reprovado
```

E depois: (pegar cada valor)

```sql
$vranalise = $row["analise"];
$vraprovado = $row["aprovado"];
$vrreprovado = $row["reprovado"];
```

E depois: (Imaginário tipo Excel: pegar o sub-total de cada status)

```sql
$totalanalise = SOMA($vranalise);
$totalaprovado = SOMA($vraprovado);
$totalreprovado = SOMA($vrreprovado);
```

E depois: (pegar valor total)

```sql
$vrgeral = ($totalanalise + $totalaprovado + $totalreprovado);
```

Sei que é meio imaginário, mas eu não sei fazer como vocês e “apanho” pra caramba! Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: ai ai ai ai ai... embaralhou tudo de novo... Desta vez fiz tudo certin no Word... copiei, colei e deu errado... aff

Comment: Consegui dar espaços... ficou 10! rs

Comment: O texto é formatado com  markdown e não HTML. Por isso que você está tendo dificuldades.

Comment: Não consegui perceber o que você está perguntando. Pode dar um exemplo de calculo e de resultados esperados?

Comment: É como o Murilão tá dizendo! Caracas!! qndo eu olho pra essa saída... nussa... é isso que eu preciso caras! Vou testar mais logo... será hein!

Comment: Obrigado pela formatação Guto... o texto ficou lindão! rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, pode ser feito usando um pivot (transformar as linhas em colunas).
Se você quiser que o select te traga 3 colunas `analise`, `aprovado` e `reprovado` com os valores somados, utilize esse select:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(sts = 1, valor, NULL)) AS 'analise',
       SUM(IF(sts = 2, valor, NULL)) AS 'aprovado',
       SUM(IF(sts = 6, valor, NULL)) AS 'reprovado'
FROM tbl_neg;
```

A saída deste select para o exemplo que você informou é:

```
analise    aprovado     reprovado  
83000       148000        35000
```

Agora se você quiser que o select te tragra as mesmas 3 colunas mas sem somar, retire o `SUM` de cada linha e você terá o resultado:

```
analise     aprovado    reprovado
23000       (null)      (null)
(null)      60000       (null)
10000       (null)      (null)
50000       (null)      (null)
(null)      (null)      20000
(null)      88000       (null)
(null)      (null)      15000
```

Pode testar o exemplo acima [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a25bc/10)

**Editado**
Conforme solicitado pelo autor, o código completo para a solução do problema utilizando o exemplo acima como base é:
1 - Alterar a mascara para que os valores em moedas sejam salvos no banco no formato americano, DE R$15.000,55 para 15000.55

```
// --------- SOMA DE VALORES - TOTAL - PORCENTAGEM ------------
$sqlnegvr = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT SUM(IF(stsneg = '1', vrpro, NULL)) AS 'analise', SUM(IF(stsneg = '2', vrpro, NULL)) AS 'aprovado', SUM(IF(stsneg = '6', vrpro, NULL)) AS 'reprovado' FROM tb_neg");
$rowvr = $sqlnegvr->fetch_assoc();
$aprovado = $rowvr["aprovado"];
$analise = $rowvr["analise"];
$reprovado = $rowvr["reprovado"];

//----- VALORES SEPARADOS
$vra = number_format($aprovado, 2,",",".");
$vraprovado = "R$ " . $vra;
$vrn = number_format($analise, 2,",",".");
$vranalise = "R$ " . $vrn;
$vrr = number_format($reprovado, 2,",",".");
$vrreprovado = "R$ " . $vrr;

//----- SOMA TUDO
$somat = ($vrn + $vra + $vrr);
$vrgt = number_format( $aprovado + $analise +$reprovado, 2,",",".");
$vrgeral = "R$ " .  $vrgt;

//----- PORCENTAGEM DE ANÁLISE
$ptvra = ($vra * 100) / $somat;
$nwpta = round($ptvra, 1);
$ptvra  = str_replace('.', ',', $nwpta);
$pcvag = str_replace('.', '', $nwpta);
$ptvrag = $pcvag;

  //----- PORCENTAGEM DE APROVADO 
$ptvrn = ($vrn * 100) / $somat;
$nwptn = round($ptvrn, 1);
$ptvrn  = str_replace('.', ',', $nwptn);
$pcvng = str_replace('.', '', $nwptn);
$ptvrng = $pcvng;

  //----- PORCENTAGEM DE REPROVADO  
$ptvrr = ($vrr * 100) / $somat;
$nwptr = round($ptvrr, 1);
$ptvrr  = str_replace('.', ',', $nwptr);
$pcvrg = str_replace('.', '', $nwptr);
$ptvrrg = $pcvrg;
```

Comment: Opa Murilão! Como vai amigão? Obrigado pela gentileza da resposta viu... Vou testar daqui a pouquinho... qndo eu vejo essa saída aí... cara, mal posso esperar pra ver... Tá cheio de centavos nestes valores... Será hein? que o SUM não vai arrendondar hein? Valeu cara!

Comment: @Infonet o SUM não deve arredondar, ele vai somar as casas de centavos normalmente, ali no exemplo ele não mostra as casas de centavos pois as mesmas são 0, se foses um valor maior que 0 iriam aparecer.

Comment: Ô amigão... pera aí... muito obrigado! Mas 10.250,00 + 10.100,55 = 10.350,55 não é? Pois é... aqui dá 20.35 aff

Comment: correção: 20.350,55

Comment: Desculpa aí Murilão... o erro foi meu então de não ter explicado que haveria centavos... (este fórum aqui é meio complicado com perguntas, parece não gostar delas rsrs... brincadeirinha). Mais alguém com alguma ideia genial? :)

Comment: @Infonet, não estou te entendendo, você quer que arredonde ou não? Na soma 10.250,00 + 10.100,55 utilizando o SUM o resultado vai ser 20350,55, não é isso que você precisa? Qual o valor que você quer que apareça? veja um teste usando a soma citada [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e24f9/1).

Comment: Uai cara, eu só tô dizendo que pra mim aparece: 20.35 (VINTE PONTO TRINTA E CINCO) e eu fiz igualzinho CRTL + C e CTRL + V e se o SUM não está arredondando é porque eu estou maluco!

Comment: @Infonet entendi, faz o seguinte, para você poder conferir os valores, tira o `SUM` e roda este mesmo select, ele vai separar os valores por coluna, (como está no meu segundo exemplo) aí se puder posta esse resultado pra gente poder ver como é a sua amostra de valores.

Comment: Obrigado Murilão, eu até já resolvi o problema (arredondamento do SUM) sobre EXIBIÇÃO/SOMA; casas decimais; moeda americana/moeda "Brasil"... Se não fosse o seu exemplo de consulta SQL, eu não teria conseguido! Gostaria de postar a solução que encontrei, mas o campo aqui não cabe! Me passa seu e-mail que eu te envio... rsrs (será que pode issso?)

Comment: @Infonet, caso queira que eu poste, pode mandar para taso@mail-maker.net

Comment: Enviei amigão! olha lá cara.... vlw

Comment: @Infonet, pronto editei a resposta e adicionei o código que você me informou! Obs: Caso a resposta lhe ajudou por favor considere marca-la como correta para ajudar outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida.

Comment: Sim cara, é isso aí, mas não podemos deixar de comentar que no banco, os valores em moeda devem ser gravados em formato americano: DE R$1.500,55 PARA 1500.55. Obrigado e que Deus te ilumine!

Comment: @Infonet ok, adicionei a informação! Que Deus lhe ilumine também e boa codificação!